# Is there a neurological explanation of acquired tastes?

Tags: neuroscience, learning

People acquire tastes through exposure. This includes the "mere exposure effect" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mere-exposure_effect). Also, music heard more often are more likely to sound pleasing to the ear (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5374342/).

While there is ample *behavioral* evidence of such "familiarity increases preference* phenomenon, I have failed to find clear neurological explanations. Are there neurological explanations?